# Relative Layout with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to set my ImageButtons in a horizontal scroll view that appears under the frame layout. Below is what I have done so far. However, this scrolls everything, including my frame layout. How do I avoid that? Or in another way to look at it, I'm trying to take my navigation drawer and lay it down instead of popping out from the side? Maybe there's a way to replicate that? Overall goal is to get something that looks similar to the old blackberry scroll menu.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DMActivity">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="900px"></FrameLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:src="@drawable/directmessage_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:src="@drawable/instantmessage_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_InstantMessage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_DirectMessages"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_InstantMessage"
            android:src="@drawable/reports_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Reports"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/conference_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Conference"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Reports"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/account_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Account"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_Conference"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/filetransfer_button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_FileTransfer"
            android:layout_below="@id/container"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Account"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:padding="20px"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="datamotion.dmandroidclient.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well, but I use this library to do horizontal scroll, you can implement this horizontal listView and inside it put your ImageButtons just like you would do with a vertical ListView.

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, what's the difference between this and HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: You are welcome. This is just like a normal ListView, but horizontal, this will let you scroll horizontally just the items inside this horizontal ListView